# Getting SQL Server Activity Monitor's Output using t-SQL

Tags: sql-server

How to get the SQL Server Activity Monitor's output using T-SQL???

Comment: Which part are you interested in?  What are you trying to achieve?  Would something like the free stored procedures discussed (and since significantly improved on) [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/why-i-dont-use-sql-server-activity-monitor/) be of any use?

Comment: "I just need a query which can display the output of Activity Monitor ." Like all running processed information, active queries with stored procedure name , active expensive queries, wait types, elapsed time, use who has executed the query , host name , app name from which query is being executed and I should be able to filter the data output.

Comment: Run a trace (Profiler or Extended Events) filtered on Application Name "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio". That will capture the T-SQL Activity Monitor uses to get that information,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **In order to get exactly same output as Activity Monitor; I have created a following script.**

If you use this script, you don't need sp_who2 or activity monitor to run.

**The script that I have created will display the following things:**

- [Session ID]
- [User Process]
- [Login]
- [Blocked By]
- [Head Blocker]
- [DatabaseName]
- [Task State]
- [Command]
- [statement_text] --It will display the statement which is being executed presently.
- [command_text] ----- It will display the Stored Procedure's Name.
- [Total CPU (ms)]
- 'Elapsed Time (in Sec)'
- [Wait Time (ms)]
- [Wait Type]
- [Wait Resource]
- [Memory Use (KB)]
- [Host Name]
- [Net Address]
- [Workload Group]
- [Application]

> **My Activity Monitor's Script is as follows:**

```
/* ACTIVITY MONITOR'S OUTPUT along with statement_text and command_text */ /* Processes */ 
SELECT [Session ID] = s.session_id, 
       [User Process] = CONVERT(CHAR(1), s.is_user_process), 
       [Login] = s.login_name, 
       [Blocked By] = ISNULL(CONVERT (varchar, w.blocking_session_id), ''), 
         [Head Blocker]  =
    CASE
        -- session has an active request, is blocked, but is blocking others or session is idle but has an open tran and is blocking others
        WHEN r2.session_id IS NOT NULL AND (r.blocking_session_id = 0 OR r.session_id IS NULL) THEN '1'
        -- session is either not blocking someone, or is blocking someone but is blocked by another party
        ELSE ''
    END,
                        [DatabaseName] = ISNULL(db_name(r.database_id), N''), 
                        [Task State] = ISNULL(t.task_state, N''), 
                        [Command] = ISNULL(r.command, N''), 
                        [statement_text] = Substring(st.TEXT, (r.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1, 
                                            ( ( CASE r.statement_end_offset WHEN - 1 THEN Datalength(st.TEXT)
                                            ELSE r.statement_end_offset 
                                            END - r.statement_start_offset ) / 2 ) + 1), ----It will display the statement which is being executed presently.

 [command_text] =Coalesce(Quotename(Db_name(st.dbid)) + N'.' + Quotename(Object_schema_name(st.objectid, st.dbid)) + N'.' + Quotename(Object_name(st.objectid, st.dbid)), ''), -- It will display the Stored Procedure's Name.

 [Total CPU (ms)] = r.cpu_time,
 r.total_elapsed_time / (1000.0) 'Elapsed Time (in Sec)',
                                 [Wait Time (ms)] = ISNULL(w.wait_duration_ms, 0),
                                 [Wait Type] = ISNULL(w.wait_type, N''),
                                 [Wait Resource] = ISNULL(w.resource_description, N''),
                                 [Total Physical I/O (MB)] = (s.reads + s.writes) * 8 / 1024,
                                 [Memory Use (KB)] = s.memory_usage * 8192 / 1024, 
 --[Open Transactions Count] = ISNULL(r.open_transaction_count,0),
 --[Login Time]    = s.login_time,
 --[Last Request Start Time] = s.last_request_start_time,

 [Host Name] = ISNULL(s.host_name, N''),
 [Net Address] = ISNULL(c.client_net_address, N''), 

 -- [Execution Context ID] = ISNULL(t.exec_context_id, 0),
 -- [Request ID] = ISNULL(r.request_id, 0),
 [Workload Group] = N'',
                     [Application] = ISNULL(s.program_name, N'')
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections c ON (s.session_id = c.session_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r ON (s.session_id = r.session_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_os_tasks t ON (r.session_id = t.session_id
                                      AND r.request_id = t.request_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ( -- In some cases (e.g. parallel queries, also waiting for a worker), one thread can be flagged as
 -- waiting for several different threads.  This will cause that thread to show up in multiple rows
 -- in our grid, which we don't want.  Use ROW_NUMBER to select the longest wait for each thread,
 -- and use it as representative of the other wait relationships this thread is involved in.
 SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY waiting_task_address
                           ORDER BY wait_duration_ms DESC) AS row_num 
   FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks ) w ON (t.session_id = w.session_id)
AND w.row_num = 1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests r2 ON (r.session_id = r2.blocking_session_id) OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS st 

WHERE s.session_Id > 50 -- Ignore system spids.

ORDER BY s.session_id --,[Total CPU (ms)] desc ;
```

Comment: I have commented out some columns in the query, like: 

 --[Open Transactions Count] = ISNULL(r.open_transaction_count,0),


 --[Login Time]    = s.login_time,

 --[Last Request Start Time] = s.last_request_start_time,

So if you want can also add or remove the columns as per your requirement and you can also filter out the data DatabaseName wise.



I hope you all will like this script.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are looking for, but this should give you something similar what you see on the activity monitor (not completely but similar).

```
SELECT
    P.spid,
    RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MS, DATEDIFF(MS, P.last_batch, GETDATE()), '1900-01-01'), 121), 12) AS [BATCH_DURATION],
    P.program_name,
    P.hostname AS HOST_NAME,
    P.loginame AS LOGIN_NAME
FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses AS P
WHERE 
    P.spid > 50 AND
    P.status NOT IN ('background', 'sleeping') AND
    P.cmd NOT IN 
    (
        'AWAITING COMMAND',
        'MIRROR HANDLER',
        'LAZY WRITER',
        'CHECKPOINT SLEEP',
        'RA MANAGER'
    )
ORDER BY 2
```

The reason we are looking for `SPID > 50` is because processes that has ID smaller than 50 belongs to internal operations. Anything greater than 50 should be for user actions.

Also, you can see all the blockings etc. on a db, you could try something like this.

```
SELECT
    db.name AS DB_NAME,
    tl.request_session_id AS REQUESTING_SESSION,
    wt.blocking_session_id AS BLOCKING_SESSION,
    OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) AS BLOCKED_OBJECT,
    tl.resource_type AS RESOURCE_TYPE,
    h1.TEXT AS REQUEST_QUERY,
    h2.TEXT AS BLOCKING_QUERY,
    tl.request_mode
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS tl
INNER JOIN sys.databases db ON db.database_id = tl.resource_database_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks AS wt ON tl.lock_owner_address =     wt.resource_address
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.hobt_id = tl.resource_associated_entity_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec1 ON ec1.session_id =     tl.request_session_id
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections ec2 ON ec2.session_id =     wt.blocking_session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec1.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h1
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec2.most_recent_sql_handle) AS h2
```

You can possibly combine these to get what exactly you are looking for.
Hope this helps.

Comment: But I have just created a script which will give the same output as Activity Monitor..